# Decompile a class/type created dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection, cil, reflection.emit, decompiler

I'm creating types dynamically by using emit. I'm quite new to this, so I'd like to have look at the code, that I've created, just to make sure it's correct.

Is it possible to have a look at the generated code? What's an appropriate way to to this?

[Edit]
Title corrected

Comment: R' Emit is quite difficult compared to Code DOM.  Plus the latter produces code as a first requirement not as an after thought :)

Comment: Is writing the assembly to disk using the `AssemblyBuilder.Save()` method an option in your use-case? That would be the easy way.

Comment: I've tried to save a dll with AssemblyBuilder.Save(), unfortunately, I can't see anthing in there. I'm using ILSpy to decompile the dll.

Comment: If ILSpy shows nothing, chances are high there is nothing. Did you call the `TypeBuilder.CreateType()` Method on each dynamic type? You have to do this on every dynamic type.

Comment: Yes, I did call TypeBuilder.CreateType(). And the basics work fine. I can create some fields and properties and even an attribute to the properties. The next step, however, has to be, implementing some basic logic (simple if-statements). So, I want to ensure, that the code is written correctly.

Comment: Is your decompiled assembly completely empty or does it contain just types/fields/... but no code? Be sure to use the IL view in ILSpy to be undepended of some interpretations the decompiler does while generating c# code.

Comment: Quick guess, check if the module DLL name matches the assembly name when saving.

Answer (score 0):

To dump the content of a dynamic assembly you can use this pattern:

```cs
// create a name
AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName("MyDynamicAssembly");

// create an assembly builder which can be dumped to disk. This is essential.
AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

// define the main module
ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name, assemblyName.Name + ".dll");

// define your type, the visibility accessor can be whatever, in this sample it is "public"
TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("Type1", TypeAttributes.Public);

// seal the type, and get it's runtime descriptor. From now on, you can use the type
Type t = tb.CreateType();

// dump the assembly in the current directory, use an overload to specify the location
ab.Save(assemblyName.Name + ".dll");
```

This way you can inspect your assembly. More on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder?view=netframework-4.8).

Note that if your intent is to define methods that can be called and you are not interested in the whole type definition, you can greatly simply the generation by the using the [`DynamicMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-define-and-execute-dynamic-methods) class.

The `DynamicMethod` class is reponsible for handling efficiently the generation of a single method, without the overhead (in term of memory) of generating a dynamic assembly.